# Overriding Django's ModelAdmin methods

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to do some custom form processing. I think the best way to go here is extending ModelAdmin's [changeform_view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1327) method because it's the one responsible for handling the form and inserting/updating records. Something like this:

```
class ArticleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # my custom form processing here
    super(ArticleAdmin, self).changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None)
```

However, nothing happens. I even tried to take this to the extreme and did this:

```
class ArticleAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_content=None):
        pass
```

Updating the object works as normal, I would've expected anything but that.

I restarted the development server. It's my understanding that some parts of Django's admin don't work that well with the reloader, so I ruled this out already.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I just figured it out. For what I'm trying to achieve the method to be extended is save_model().

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    pass
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Silly question, but how are you registering that modeladmin class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Like this: admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out. For what I'm trying to achieve the method to be extended is save_model().

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    pass
```

Hope it helps.